# Full-stack vs Full Stack, Back-end vs Back end, Front-end vs Front end

Tags: orthography

Software Developers use the dash interchangeably for these terms.

Front-end meaning one works on the "Front End" of an application (e.g. HTML), Back-end meaning one works on the "Back End" of an application (e.g. PHP), and Full-stack meaning all of the above.

Is there a proper spelling of these terms? Or does it matter?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The usual principle is that an *attributive* adjective gets hyphenated (*it was a hard-fought victory*), but a *predicative* adjective does not (*the victory was hard fought*).

The punctuation usually follows the syllabic stress. Note that in *hard-fought victory*, there is only one stressed syllable in *hard-fought*, whereas in *the victory was hard fought*, there are two stressed syllables in *hard fought*.

So you'd have *front-end system*.

The noun phrase *front end* shouldn't be hyphenated: both words are stressed.